# Merge 2 Files and throw an error if an Invalid File selected

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hi all i am having a `list box` on my Form which will display all the `.txt` files from the directory `C:`. This `list box` selection mode is set to `MultiExtended`.

My condition to check whether the file is valid or not will be checked using the condition as each and every line content of the selected file should be `*94`*. If this one satisifes then only it is said to be a valid file. I have written a code for this too but as i am checking in the loop and at a time i can only read one file content this was working fine. But i have to check initially all the selected files matches the condition or not if ok then i have to do the remaining code if not i would like to display error

My code on Button Click

```
  private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstACH.SelectedIndices.Count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select 2 Files To Merge");
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < lstACH.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                strFile = lstACH.SelectedItems[i].ToString();
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(strFile);
                if (LinesHaveCorrectLength(lines, 94)) // Here i am checking but at a tym i am checking one file only i have to check for all and if ok then the remaining code has to be executed
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Stream myStream;

                        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

                        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
                        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.txt)|*.txt";
                        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
                        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
                        saveFileDialog1.ValidateNames = true;
                        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            Append.FileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                            if (Append.FileName.Contains(" \\/:*?<>|"))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("File name should not contain \\/:*?<>|", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                                {
                                    Append.FileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                                    myStream.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Append.FileName, true))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srBatch = new StreamReader(strFile))
                        {
                            while (srBatch.Peek() >= 0)
                            {
                                strReadLine = srBatch.ReadLine();
                                if (strReadLine.StartsWith("1"))
                                {
                                    if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        strFileHeader = strReadLine;
                                        sw.WriteLine(strFileHeader);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (strReadLine.StartsWith("5"))
                                {
                                    strBtchHeader = strReadLine;
                                    if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        Btchno = Convert.ToInt32(strReadLine.Substring(87, 7));
                                        BatchCnt = Convert.ToInt16(Btchno);
                                    }
                                    if (i > 0)
                                    {
                                        BatchCnt++;
                                        strBtchHeader = strBtchHeader.Substring(0, 87) + Convert.ToString(BatchCnt.ToString().PadLeft(7, (char)48));
                                    }
                                    sw.WriteLine(strBtchHeader);
                                }
                                if (strReadLine.StartsWith("6"))
                                {
                                    strEntryDetail = strReadLine;
                                    if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        strTraceNo = strEntryDetail.Substring(87, 7);
                                        EntryCount = Convert.ToInt16(strTraceNo);
                                    }
                                    if (i > 0)
                                    {
                                        EntryCount++;
                                        strEntryDetail = strEntryDetail.Substring(0, 87) + EntryCount.ToString().PadLeft(7, (char)48);
                                    }
                                    sw.WriteLine(strEntryDetail);
                                }
                                if (strReadLine.StartsWith("8"))
                                {
                                    strBtchCntrl = strReadLine;
                                    if (i > 0)
                                    {
                                        //btchEntry++;
                                        strBtchCntrl = strBtchCntrl.Substring(0, 87) + BatchCnt.ToString().PadLeft(7, (char)48);
                                    }
                                    sw.WriteLine(strBtchCntrl);
                                }
                                if (strReadLine.StartsWith("9"))
                                {
                                    strFileCntrl = strReadLine;

                                    strBtchCnt = strReadLine.Substring(1, 6);
                                    strEntrycnt = strReadLine.Substring(13, 8);
                                    strEntryHash = strReadLine.Substring(21, 10);
                                    strDebitAmnt = strReadLine.Substring(31, 12);
                                    strCreditAmnt = strReadLine.Substring(43, 12);

                                    BtchCnt += Convert.ToDouble(strBtchCnt);
                                    Entrycnt += Convert.ToDouble(strEntrycnt);
                                    EntryHash += Convert.ToDouble(strEntryHash);
                                    DebitAmnt += Convert.ToDouble(strDebitAmnt);
                                    CreditAmnt += Convert.ToDouble(strCreditAmnt);

                                    if (i == lstACH.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
                                    {
                                        strFileCntrl = strFileCntrl.Substring(0, 1) + BtchCnt.ToString().PadLeft(6, (char)48) + strFileCntrl.Substring(7, (strFileCntrl.Length - 7));
                                        strFileCntrl = strFileCntrl.Substring(0, 13) + Entrycnt.ToString().PadLeft(8, (char)48) + strFileCntrl.Substring(21, (strFileCntrl.Length - 21));
                                        strFileCntrl = strFileCntrl.Substring(0, 21) + EntryHash.ToString().PadLeft(10, (char)48) + strFileCntrl.Substring(31, (strFileCntrl.Length - 31));
                                        strFileCntrl = strFileCntrl.Substring(0, 31) + DebitAmnt.ToString().PadLeft(12, (char)48) + strFileCntrl.Substring(43, (strFileCntrl.Length - 43));
                                        strFileCntrl = strFileCntrl.Substring(0, 43) + CreditAmnt.ToString().PadLeft(12, (char)48) + strFileCntrl.Substring(55, (strFileCntrl.Length - 55));
                                        sw.WriteLine(strFileCntrl);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (i == lstACH.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("File Has Been Merged Successfully");
                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("One of the Selected File is not a Valid ACH File");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Checking for Each and every line Length

```
 private static bool LinesHaveCorrectLength(string[] lines, int expectedLineLength)
    {
        foreach (string item in lines)
        {
            if (item.Length != expectedLineLength)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ummm Long question but still not clear... can you tell us in short what you want to do?

Comment: Hmmm i am selecting 2 files from list box and i have to check whether the files are valid or not if valid only the code has to be executed if one file fails my condition i will display a error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check them all first - and if all good, THEN begin merge.

```
        if (lstACH.SelectedIndices.Count != 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select 2 Files To Merge");
            return;
        }

        foreach (String fileName in lstACH.SelectedItems)
        {
            if( LinesHaveCorrectLength( File.ReadAllLines(fileName), 94 ) == false )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File: " + fileName + " has an incorrect line length");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Now process them all again to merge:
        foreach(String fileName in lstACH.SelectedItems)
        {
            // ... do merge logic
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok according to your comment it looks like First you want both files to be validated. if that is the case then:

*(There could be many ways , this is one of them)*

First define a Function to do the checking for all files:

```
public bool AreFilesValid(ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection filenames)
{
    int count = filenames.Count;
    bool valid = false;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        string strFile = filenames[i].ToString();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(strFile);
        if(LinesHaveCorrectLength(lines, 94)) { valid=true;  }
        else  {  valid = false;   }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Then call it in your if condition, i.e just change following lines:

```
     ...
     strFile = lstACH.SelectedItems[i].ToString();
     lines = File.ReadAllLines(strFile);
     if (LinesHaveCorrectLength(lines, 94))
     {
     ...
```

To only this:

```
  ...
  if (AreFilesValid(lstACH.SelectedItems))
  {
  ...
```

You have already got your `else` statement down the code to catch when this `if` condition fails.